# dhcpd.log problem

Tags: dhcp

I stupidly deleted /var/log/dhcpd.log

So, I stopped the service, created a new dhcpd.log file with the same ownership / rights etc. as the old file, and restarted the service.

But nothing is being written to the log file now.

Am I missing something?

Comment: are you using ubuntu 16.xx? How does your dhcpd.conf  and syslog.conf file looks like? Have you checked that?

Comment: Did you get any errors? Maybe there is just nothing to be logged so far .. ?

Comment: I'm using 14.04dhcpd.conf has the line  log-facility local7;

Comment: Oh, and just to confirm, it was logging to dhcpd.log just fine. I just deleted the file by mistake. But now, after recreating and restarting the service, it isnt logging

Answer (score 1):

dhcpd is using syslog for logging so you need to restart the service `rsyslogd`.

Comment: I did try that, and it had no effect. But after waiting until the following day it started working again. I guess it was something to do with the log file rotation which helped sort itself out.